# Video-Js click event : how not to fire on controlbar buttons

Tags: javascript, events, click, video.js

I'm new to Video-js that i want to use to put a video player on my website and I'm trying to add custom 'click' event (or 'tap' for mobile device) on the video, to override the natural behavior of video-js player. When I click or tap the video, I wish to play next video, instead of toogle Play/Pause the video.

The code works, but the event fires even when I click on a button of the controlbar where there is the controls button like: play, volume, fullscreen.

Is there another event name to use if you want the click event is fired only when user click on the video (but not on a button of the controlbar) or is there a test to do in the event function to test if click was done on the controlbar to return before doing code ?

For the moment I have only this:

```
var player = videojs('videojs-player', {}, function() {//some code} ); 

player.on('click', function() { 
    alert('video was clicked'); 
// do something
};
```

Thnak you very much for any help.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use the event object (`evt` in the example below) that's passed to your click handler to identify where on the player the user clicked.

In the example below we look at the `target` property of the event object to ascertain which element triggered the event. We then check the `tag​Name` property. If it's not equal to `VIDEO` we ignore the click.

```js
var player = videojs('videojs-player', {}, function() {
  //some code
});

player.on('click', function(evt) { 
  if (evt.target.tagName === 'VIDEO') {
    console.log('video was clicked'); 
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/5.4.6/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/5.4.6/video.min.js"></script>
<video id="videojs-player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
  controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264">
  <source src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/big-buck-bunny-1080p@0.0.6/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
</video>
```